# Bins for fixed interval in Longitudinal data and plotting it over the period of time by categories

Tags: r, line-plot, bins, longitudinal

It is longitudinal data; ID wise values are repeating 4 times in every tick of 20 steps. Then this experiments repeats. For the datafarme below I want bins based for every tick time steps for the categories of land based on the values of X.
Bins can be 3 for every time interval for land type (Small, medium and large) each.
I want to see timeline of bins of X based on categories of Land.
Any help will be appreciated. I have added possibly a picture of how data may look like for ggplot and plot as bins or dots may look like as in picture.

```
   Seed(123)
ID = 1:5
Time = rep (c(1,2,3,4,5), each = 20)
Type = 1:25
data <- data.frame( IDn = rep(ID,20), Time,  Land = rep(Type, 40), y = rnorm(100,0,1), x = runif(100,0,1))
data$Land= ifelse (data$Land > 15,"large farmers", ifelse(data$Land <=5, "small farmers", "medium-farmers"))
```

[image]

[image]

Edit: Question for labeling the faceting variable and dot plots.

[image]

Comment: @Ronak shah; I have tried my best to reduce the data and also added that how possibly data and graph may look like.  or another which may represent development over ticks. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would help -

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>%
  group_by(Time, Land) %>%
  mutate(x = cut(x, c(0, 0.25, 0.75, 1))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  count(Time, Land, x) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Time, n, fill = Land) + geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah. This solved my problem. What to be changed if  bar of bins are to be replaced with dots? and if legend for X to be added as bar shows the count but not the categories of x we have made. that what is this count for!

Comment: I have added facet_grid(~x, nrow(2)). But can't figure out that how this will be labled on the graph that facet shows values of X. Can you please help?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear to me. Do you need `ggplot() + aes(x, n, fill = Land) + geom_col(position = 'dodge')` ? keeping `x` on X-axis ?

Comment: I have just edit and shared graph. I hope now my question is making sense! Can you please see that @Ronak.

Comment: Hi, I don't think this is related to your original question. Please ask that as a new question so that this post focusses only on one question and will not confuse future readers.